# How to make text visible in an android ListView

Tags: android, xml

I am working on listview, I want to make the text visible that is given to it in the textview in xml file. The list items i have added in list is showing correctly (visible ) but not the text. I want that text visible too need help for it.

[image]

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="Gender:"
        android:textColor="#FF00FF"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:
Putting data into adapter

```
if (success == 1) {


                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);


                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);


                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);


                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_GENDER, gender);


                        productsList.add(map);
                    }






                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllPersonActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME, TAG_GENDER},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.gender });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Comment: you can append text to textview using `append` method

Comment: please post adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the text with data that filled in list view.

ie, 
    YourTextView.setText("Name: " + listitem);

like this. is the simplest way.

Comment: What in case of the 'ListAdapter' i have used in above code ?

Comment: append it when you put data to productsList. iam not sure. just try it. let me know if it worked.

Comment: congrats. the idea you have given also worked so i found the second solution. I did what is that was using hasmap `(map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name: "+name);` and after that i put it in `productsList.add(map);` and then in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which `TextView` are you having problems with, but the first one sets

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

which will keep it from appearing.

Comment: i am having problem with the next two TextViews the first one visibility is set to gone wont show it there but why the next two is invisible, even i have set the property to visible?

Comment: Mmh try replacing all three fill_parent's for wrap_contents, and add a weight=1 for every textView

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is due to the same background color of LinearLayout and font color of the contents. Try the following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gender"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:text="Gender:"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question  just to help those face problem like me. I have found the solution although its not a good one but worked for me and changing it to different `Views` can help in different way to show text or something else. The problem was my code (adapter) was replacing the parsed string on `xml` `TextViews` so i put another `TextView` above each item came from list.

> Here is the XML i have made changes

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <!--This is to show the label "Name" above the listitem (whatever name) come from java code parsed, json  -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtshowname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<!-- This TextView will contain the listitems loaded from server -->

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



 <!--This is to show the label "Gender" above the listitem (whatever gender) come from java code parsed, json  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtshowGender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#FF00FF"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And also this little change worked for me

```
map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name" + name);
                    map.put(TAG_GENDER, "Gender" + gender);


                    productsList.add(map);
```